# How to refrence files in SpringDoc OpenAPI3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

I have Springboot project where i want to documentate my API:

Here the exemple of the Webservice am working on:

```
    @ApiResponses(
        value = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", content =  @Content(
                        mediaType = "*/*",
                        schema = @Schema(implementation = Object.class),
                        examples = {
                                @ExampleObject(name = "boo",
                                summary = "example of boo",
                                ref = "#/swagger/Planner/semi_planif_200_response.json")
                        }

                ))
        }
)
@PostMapping(value = "/startSemiPlanification", produces = "application/json")
private ResponseEntity<Object> startSemiPlanner( @RequestBody PlanificationDto planificationData,
                                                @RequestParam(name = "groupByUserCode", required = false) Optional<Boolean> groupByUserCode,
                                            @RequestParam(name = "range", defaultValue = "18") Integer range
```

My Problem is that  Swagger cannot resolve this reference   **ref = "#/swagger/Planner/semi_planif_200_response.json"**   i have even tried with the absolute path and it didn't work:
[image: The Error Message from swagger]

Here is  files path:

[image: File path]

Comment: What was the actual solution other than accepted answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References are not resolved in compile time instead after  running the project the swagger engine will resolve the references as they were static resources within the server:

```
 $ref= resources/swagger/user.json
```

if we are running our instance in localhost then the resource will be fetched from this url: `localhost:8080/resources/swagger/user.json`

**Tip**: make sure that spring resources handler is placing  the targeted resources on the specified location!

Comment: Tried your solution. indeed localhost:8080/resources/swagger/user.json is available. however swagger doesn't replace the Example ref with the content of ref's json. @Parameter(name = "myparameter" examples={@ExampleObject(name="test", ref="resources/swagger/user.json"}). Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I did not get your answer. There is no file named user.json. Which path did you use to place json file? Those are not clear. Please can you elaborate on your answer and put some images or details related to your file structure?

Comment: User.json is a file that cotains the swagger configuration for user webservices(a controller that I made), the idea to not provide path for static configuration files because that will not work but you must provide a rest api that will fetch the static files and return a json as response and this solution should work

Comment: Thanks a lot for the question. I am also facing similar issue where I am trying to load the example file from my resources folder. But your answer does not seem to work for me. I see in my `swaggerUI` 2 options based on the examples I have added but when I see the contents of that template it does not match with the data I have provided in the file. Can you please help me with the issue?

Comment: I have posted my question on the Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71616547/7584240 If you get a chance can you please have a look and provide some response?